# Calculate weights for a similarity score

Tags: algorithm, math

Assume there is a dataset as follows:

```
dataA: {
  attribute1: x,
  attribute2: y,
  attribute3: z
}
```

I want to calculate the correlation between similar structured data (Eg: `dataA, dataB, dataC ...`)

And I have a similarity measure for each attribute of each dataset. (Eg: similarity of `x` with other values of `attribute1` is 0.11, similarity of `y` with other values of `attribute2` is 0.22, similarity of `z` with other values of `attribute3` is 0.33)

I'm going to present the correlation score in a weighted average approach where a weight is defined for each attribute (Eg: weight of `attribute1` is `w1` etc.):

```
Score for dataA = { (0.11 x w1) + (0.22 x w2) + (0.33 x w3) } / {w1 + w2 + w3}
```

If I'm going to conduct an experiment to find the optimal weights, how can I do it?

**UPDATE:**

Can I conduct an experiment to check the probability of each attribute value to be changed and then use that value somehow?

Answer (score 1):

How about [the assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) or [the simplex method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm)?